# get a specific value by key from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = $wo['products_sub_categories']];
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($ar) {
return ($ar['id'] == 22);
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

I'm using this to get a specific value by key from a multidimensional array where id is equal to some value.
my array returns

```
Array
(
    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 209
            [category_id] => 11
            [lang_key] => 2092
            [type] => product
            [brands] => 
            [lang] => Mobile Phones
        )

)
```

But I need only "Mobile Phones" as output.

Comment: You're using print_r to return the entire array. Might want to try something along the lines of var_dump($arr[0][lang]);   Also: Line 1 includes an additional closing "]", not sure if this is a typo or a flaw in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_column`

```
$arr = $wo['products_sub_categories'];
$arr2 = array_column($arr, 'lang');
print_r($arr2);
```